# What is the right way to layout elements in a table order?

Tags: html, css

[image]

---

Hi i want to position my elements like in this picture.

I tried to use flexbox but the second row required more effort to place the elements differently

I am not sure if I should use flexbox/grid or normal table for this kind of layout

Is using the table tag is not preferable? I would really like to see a code suggestion for this layout.. Thanks ahead

Comment: 1. Please add the code that you wrote to achieve the desired result
2. What do labels mean in your example? Do you want to place them next to `<div>` boxes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you need simple grid.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    10
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    12
  </div>
</div>
```